Compatibility issue installing MMSegmentation on macOS
I tried installing MMSegmentation following the instructions on (https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmsegmentation/blob/main/docs/en/get_started.md) for the CPU version on macOS, but I encountered compatibility issues with the packages.
Here are the steps I followed:

I created and activated the environment:
conda create --name openmmlab python=3.8 -y
conda activate openmmlab


I installed PyTorch (version 2.1.x) compatible with MMCV as indicated here.

I installed MMEngine:
pip install -U openmim
mim install mmengine


I installed MMCV following the instruction of the point (2) using:
pip install mmcv==2.1.0 -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cpu/torch2.1/index.html


I installed MMSegmentation:
pip install "mmsegmentation>=1.0.0"


I downloaded the configuration and checkpoint files pspnet_r50-d8_4xb2-40k_cityscapes-512x1024.py and pspnet_r50-d8_512x1024_40k_cityscapes_20200605_003338-2966598c.pth and placed them in the working directory.

Finally, I ran the recommended Python code for inference. However, I received the following package compatibility error:
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mmcv/_ext.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: (__ZN3c106detail19maybe_wrap_dim_slowIxEET_S2_S2_b)
Referenced from: '/opt/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mmcv/_ext.cpython-39-darwin.so'
Expected in: '/opt/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.dylib'



I also tried installing both mmcv-lite and mmcv-full, but the compatibility issue persists even though I followed the specified package versions. Could you please provide any suggestions?
My computer is a MacBook Pro with a 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 quad-core processor.
